# How to generate Unique CSS Selector Automatically

Tags: html, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

Now I'm using Chrome dev tools.

What I want to do is that "If I clicked html element, Chrome automatically have generated unique css selector of that element".

Is there any method ? chrome extension or something.

thanks.

Comment: right-click element in dev-tools tree view > Copy > Copy-selector

Answer (score 0):

Go through this link you will get the unique [CSS Selector Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/get-unique-css-selector/lkfaghhbdebclkklgjhhonadomejckai?hl=en)

Add this extension in your Chrome browser. After adding this extension If you want to find unique CSS selector of any item on your page. Open context menu and Copy to clipboard.It will help you to find an unique selector of any page. Visit the above link you will get the more guideline.

Comment: you are hero 111